# Nmap stalling after reboot

Tags: nmap

I use nmap to find devices on my network that has the port 5300 open. At first it worked great. I could find devices in no time, but then I rebooted my computer and now nmap just stalls during the scan and does nothing. Here's my command with nmap 7.80:

`nmap -Pn -oG - -p5300 --min-parallelism 5 --max-rtt-timeout 100ms 10.42.0/24`

Any idea ? There is no router in between my devices and the computer I run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it seems my research on this were unsuccessful through google but this related question fixed my issue: [nmap scan takes 50 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235329/nmap-scan-takes-50-minutes?rq=1)

Basically removing -Pn prevent nmap from trying to ping 10k ports on 255 devices. It wasn't stalling, simply doing ALOT of pings.